# How can I add a set of rows to each distinct observation in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I am looking to automate a process in R that was previously done by hand and is very time consuming. I'd like to add a series of observations from one dataframe to each unique variable in another. An example using data will probably illustrate this better...

Table one contains a number of observations for each animal, this is the table where I will want to add a set of rows for each type of animal.

| Animal | Colour | Temperament |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Black | Calm |
| Dog | Beige | Anxious |
| Cat | White | Playful |

Table two shows the rows that should be applied to each animal.

| Colour | Temperament |
| --- | --- |
| Brown | Control |
| Beige | Control |
| White | Control |

The final table should look something like:

| Animal | Colour | Temperament |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Black | Calm |
| Dog | Beige | Anxious |
| Cat | White | Playful |
| Cat | Brown | Control |
| Cat | Beige | Control |
| Cat | White | Control |
| Dog | Brown | Control |
| Dog | Beige | Control |
| Dog | White | Control |

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction? Pref using tidyverse over base R (but not essential :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.We create an easy to use and reproducible example data

```
d1 <- data.frame(an = c("c", "d", "c"), 
                 cl = c("bl", "be", "wh"),
                 tm = c("cl", "an", "pl"))

d2 <- data.frame(cl = c("br", "be", "wh"),
                 tm = "cn")
```

2.Using `expand_grid` in combination with `tidyr::full_join` to expand the data.frame `d1` to the desired form:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d1 %>% 
  full_join(expand_grid(d2, an = unique(d1$an)))
```

This returns:

> ```
>   an cl tm
> 1  c bl cl
> 2  d be an
> 3  c wh pl
> 4  c br cn
> 5  d br cn
> 6  c be cn
> 7  d be cn
> 8  c wh cn
> 9  d wh cn
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(d2, an = d1$an) %>% 
    full_join(d1)
Joining, by = c("cl", "tm", "an")
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  cl    tm    an   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 be    cn    c    
2 be    cn    d    
3 br    cn    c    
4 br    cn    d    
5 wh    cn    c    
6 wh    cn    d    
7 bl    cl    c    
8 be    an    d    
9 wh    pl    c
```

#### data

```
d1 <- structure(list(an = c("c", "d", "c"), cl = c("bl", "be", "wh"
), tm = c("cl", "an", "pl")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

d2 <- structure(list(cl = c("br", "be", "wh"), tm = c("cn", "cn", "cn"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```